# How to make Steam use Helvetica in its GUI instead of Arial?

Tags: windows-8, fonts, steam

I searched the web and found out that there's one solution: editing the steam.styles file (\Program Files (x86)\Steam\resource\styles\steam.styles).

I edited it, changed the line from:

```
// cool we can define font-families here as well
basefont="Arial"
basefont="Helvetica" [$OSX]
```

To:

```
// cool we can define font-families here as well
basefont="Helvetica"
basefont="Helvetica" [$OSX]
```

But to no avail, because Steam will always launch with the dialog box "Checking for updates", and "Validating (something)" and the modified file would be changed to default (back to basefont="Arial").

So are there any ways to make Helvetica font the default font in Steam's GUI?

== Update ==

I've already installed Helvetica font.

== Update 2 ==

As suggested, setting the file "steam.styles" as read-only didn't work, Steam probably deleted and wrote a new file.

== Update 3 == [solved]

Edited the file; deny all users and system accounts for write access ONLY, and now Steam managed to display the desired font.

Comment: This is related, if not a direct duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/613253/is-it-possible-to-install-helvetica-for-microsoft-office

Comment: How is this related? I know the font name might be a little related, the whole topic isn't about "installing Helvetica for Microsoft Office", as I want Steam to display Helvetica font instead of Arial and stay that way, while the other question talks about the possibility of installing the font on a program, which is Office.

Comment: I think your problem is that you assume Windows has Helvetica installed. As stated by my previous comment's link, it does not.

Comment: Um. No, I installed Helvetica... Let me add details for this.

Comment: Ah, ok then. That was what I was missing. You can use NTFS permissions to prevent Steam to modify the file.

Comment: NTFS permissions? Okay, but how? I've never heard of that before. Thanks.

Comment: I'll explain. You can also try to make that file read-only, but that isn't granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to lock a file from being modified, on Windows. Make your modifications to the files before any of these methods.

- Making it [read-only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute#DOS_and_Windows).

  - You access the file's Properties by right-clicking it. In the General tab, a checkbok marked read-only should exist. Check it.
  - This makes the system recognize that the file shouldn't be modified. However, it isn't a set-on-stone limit, and programs may circumvent this behavior.
- Using NTFS security permissions in order to prevent Write access.

  - This is more reliable than the previous method, as it works on the file-system level.
  - In the file's Properties, access the Security tab. there, first select your username and afterwards, Deny Write permissions on the checkboxes below. Apply. A warning will appear, just accept. This will make the file completely write-proof.
    [image]

Comment: I assume that the main problem is Steam updating the `steam.styles` file, so preventing it from updating *should* work. If not, feel free to update your post.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it worked... But the interface is messed up... No words are shown... Guess I have to change to other fonts. Thank you! I will mark your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: 2 things I have to say though, [Arial looks enough like Helvetica](http://snth.net/~rlk/image/helvetica-vs-arial.png) for the differences not to be noticeable. Also, remember to deactivate this from time to time, in case Steam needs to perform an important update.

Comment: Nope, to me, Arial looks a lot different because I know quite a lot about fonts. I hate Arial, it's ugly and a cheap knockoff that defamed Helvetica. Anyways, thanks for your reminder about deactivating the file write-restriction. Will do.